# Как добавить возможность подтверждения регистрации пользователя для opencart?

Tags: opencart

В opencart при регистрации, пользователь сразу становится активным. Т.е. он не подтверждает почту при регистрации, таким образом можно наделать 100 левых аккаунтов, так как можно любой емайл подсунуть ему даже вымышленный.

Искал на сайте опенкарта расширения но не нашёл таких.

Comment: А версия ОС какая? Если совсем бесплатно, то самому и написать модуль. На форуме ocStore этот вопрос часто поднимался и варианты решения разные есть, почитайте.
[Активация покупателя по e-mail](https://opencartforum.com/topic/5908-reshenie-aktivaciya-pokupatelya-po-e-mail-bez-uchastiya-admina/) |
 [Активация пользовательского e-mail](https://opencartforum.com/topic/3230-aktivaciya-polzovatelskogo-e-mail-v-ocstore-022/) | 
 [Высылаем клиенту (при регистрации) Логин и Пароль на e-mail](https://opencartforum.com/topic/2585-vysylaem-klientu-pri-registracii-login-i-parol-na-e-mail/)

Comment: @AndrewHobbit версия самая свежая. Буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покупатели - Группы покупателей - редактировать группу по-умолчанию

Подтверждение новых покупателей - Да

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы про ботов, то в opencart, как в любой вменяемой cms, есть **capcha**. `Админка > Дополнения > Captcha` Как использовать - почитайте, хоть бы, [тут](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/ru/opencart-2-x-how-to-manage-captcharecaptcha.html).

Если речь идёт о непосредственном подтверждении акаунта через мыло-ссылку, то озадачьтесь поиском модуля или разраба, который данный функционал способен реализовать.

Comment: Капчу я уже поставил, меня интересует именно подтверждение по мылу. Модуль я нашел и заказать у разработчика я всегда успею. Меня интересовало бесплатное решение. Самый дешевый модуль стоит 20 баксов.